# Mutable Types: Why are arrays with same contents considered equal in Python & Ruby but not Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, ruby

I have been learning about mutability in Python, Ruby and Javascript. My assumption was that Ruby and Python would behave similarly to Javascript when using the comparison operator between two arrays or two objects of the same value. Why are Python and Ruby returning true when comparing arrays of same values but Javascript does not?

For example:

Python:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> y = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> x == y
True
```

Ruby:

```
> x = [1,2,3]
> y = [1,2,3]
> x == y
=> true
```

Javascript:

```
> x = [1,2,3]
> y = [1,2,3]
> x === y
false
```

Comment: Because arrays are objects in JS, and no 2 objects are equal.

Comment: Triple equal sign does not care about values but the objects themselves, that is to say, if the variables point the same memory space

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript here can be detailed info for JS arrays comparing

Comment: @TUIlover `x == y` would also be considered false in JavaScript. My understanding is that three equals is a strict type comparison operator.

Comment: @JoelHoelting it simply because javascript decide to do this. And one cannot provide equality operator in javascript custom class either.

Comment: "My assumption was that Ruby and Python would behave similarly to Javascript when using the comparison operator" bad assumption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why are Python and Ruby returning true when comparing arrays of same values but Javascript does not?

Because they are three completely different programming languages, and there is no reason to expect that they behave the same.

ECMAScript does what the ECMAScript Language Specification says it should do. Ruby does what the Ruby Language Specification says it should do. Python does what the Python Language Specification says it should do.